# Interchange of max and min

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ be two functions of $x$. Is this true
\begin{align}
\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}}~\min_{i}~f_i(x) = \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}}~\max_{i}~-f_i(x)
\end{align}
(UPDATE: I am not asking if the solution $x$ from both the problems are equal, but if the objective value at the optimum is equal or not)

If so, please prove it, else explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you mean to write "arg max" and "arg min" over $x$?

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=1$. The equation reduces to $1=-1$, which is false.

Comment: is LHS=-1*RHS true?

Comment: @dineshdileep Ah, yes, I think that works!